# VPN device filtering ASUS Asuswrt Merlin

Tags: router, vpn, openvpn, asuswrt-merlin

I've been attempting to get the following to work:
https://github.com/RMerl/asuswrt-merlin/wiki/How-to-Direct-Traffic-over-VPN-and-Drop-connections-if-VPN-goes-down

I've specifically gone through every step and even started from scratch many times but always with the same result... all the devices on the network end up going through the VPN. I have a few phones, tablets and PCs and a TV on my network. I basically want ONLY the TV to use OpenVPN and the rest to use the standard ISP connection. I've not used the last batch file as I don't need it.

My router is Asus AC68U, running Asuswrt-Merlin v. RT-AC68U_378.54_2

System Log on VPN Activation:

```
Jun 20 19:33:11 rc_service: httpd 491:notify_rc start_vpnclient1
Jun 20 19:33:11 kernel: tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
Jun 20 19:33:11 kernel: tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky <maxk@qualcomm.com>
Jun 20 19:33:13 openvpn[1113]: DEPRECATED OPTION: --tls-remote, please update your configuration
Jun 20 19:33:13 openvpn[1113]: OpenVPN 2.3.6 arm-unknown-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [MH] [IPv6] built on Jun 10 2015
Jun 20 19:33:13 openvpn[1113]: library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2a 19 Mar 2015, LZO 2.08
Jun 20 19:33:13 openvpn[1113]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Jun 20 19:33:13 openvpn[1113]: Control Channel Authentication: using 'static.key' as a OpenVPN static key file
Jun 20 19:33:13 openvpn[1113]: Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Jun 20 19:33:13 openvpn[1113]: Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Jun 20 19:33:13 openvpn[1113]: Socket Buffers: R=[122880->131072] S=[122880->131072]
Jun 20 19:33:13 openvpn[1114]: UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Jun 20 19:33:13 openvpn[1114]: UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]107.181.xx.xxx:1194
Jun 20 19:33:13 openvpn[1114]: TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]107.181.xx.xxx:1194, sid=b716b428 ba1bfb13
Jun 20 19:33:14 openvpn[1114]: VERIFY OK: depth=1, /C=US/ST=CA/L=SanFrancisco/O=Fort-Funston/CN=Fort-Funston_CA/emailAddress=me@myhost.mydomain
Jun 20 19:33:14 openvpn[1114]: VERIFY OK: nsCertType=SERVER
Jun 20 19:33:14 openvpn[1114]: VERIFY X509NAME OK: /C=US/ST=CA/O=Fort-Funston/CN=server_v1/emailAddress=me@myhost.mydomain
Jun 20 19:33:14 openvpn[1114]: VERIFY OK: depth=0, /C=US/ST=CA/O=Fort-Funston/CN=server_v1/emailAddress=me@myhost.mydomain
Jun 20 19:33:17 openvpn[1114]: Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Jun 20 19:33:17 openvpn[1114]: Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Jun 20 19:33:17 openvpn[1114]: Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Jun 20 19:33:17 openvpn[1114]: Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Jun 20 19:33:17 openvpn[1114]: Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 2048 bit RSA
Jun 20 19:33:17 openvpn[1114]: [server_v1] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]107.181.69.130:1194
Jun 20 19:33:19 openvpn[1114]: SENT CONTROL [server_v1]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Jun 20 19:33:19 openvpn[1114]: PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1,dhcp-option DNS 10.10.0.1,route 10.10.0.1,topology net30,ping 10,ping-restart 60,ifconfig 10.10.2.10 10.10.2.9'
Jun 20 19:33:19 openvpn[1114]: OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Jun 20 19:33:19 openvpn[1114]: OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Jun 20 19:33:19 openvpn[1114]: OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Jun 20 19:33:19 openvpn[1114]: OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
Jun 20 19:33:19 openvpn[1114]: TUN/TAP device tun11 opened
Jun 20 19:33:19 openvpn[1114]: TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Jun 20 19:33:19 openvpn[1114]: do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Jun 20 19:33:19 openvpn[1114]: /usr/sbin/ip link set dev tun11 up mtu 1500
Jun 20 19:33:19 openvpn[1114]: /usr/sbin/ip addr add dev tun11 local 10.10.2.10 peer 10.10.2.9
Jun 20 19:33:21 openvpn[1114]: /usr/sbin/ip route add 107.181.xx.xxx/32 via 10.24.xx.x
Jun 20 19:33:21 openvpn[1114]: /usr/sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.10.2.9
Jun 20 19:33:21 openvpn[1114]: /usr/sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.10.2.9
Jun 20 19:33:21 openvpn[1114]: /usr/sbin/ip route add 10.10.0.1/32 via 10.10.2.9
Jun 20 19:33:21 openvpn-routing: Skipping, not in routing policy mode
Jun 20 19:33:21 custom script: Running /jffs/scripts/openvpn-event (args: )
Jun 20 19:33:21 openvpn[1114]: Initialization Sequence Completed
```

Please let me know should you require any further info.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to route traffic based on the *source*, you need policy routing. Currently, you have `redirect-gateway def1` somewhere in your configuration. This causes all traffic to go through your VPN connection.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by route traffic based on source? Could you elaborate please?

Comment: You say “I basically want ONLY the TV to use OpenVPN” and that means you want to route based which device (your TV) is the source.

Comment: Ok now I understand. To give you more info. I used ExpressVPN's `*.ovpn` file. Does it mean that the settings in that are causing  the redirection? i.e. `redirect-gateway def1`. If not where should I look for this on the router?

Comment: Any guidance would be appreciated @DanielB